# CloudHub HTTPS endpoint not working

Tags: mule, mule-studio, cloudhub

I have set up an HTTPS endpoint for my mulesoft flow which is working great in local.

https://'localhost':8081/customerquote

Once I deploy it on CloudHub I am not able to contact the url using https, the URL looks like 
https://myappname.cloudhub.io/customerquote it is responding only in HTTP reporting an SSL handshake error of course.

Already tried to switch the endpoint port to 443 or 8443 without any results.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did copy the exactly example reported here and it worked

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+an+HTTPS+Service

Answer (score 1):

You need to use properties placeholders when you're deploying to CloudHub: 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Developing+a+CloudHub+Application

> If your application requires an externally accessible HTTP or HTTPS
>   port to receive messages, trigger events, or expose a web service or
>   user interface, you must declare the port using the reserved property
>   ${http.port} or ${https.port}. On CloudHub, port ${http.port} or
>   ${https.port} is assigned automatically by the platform services.
>   Traffic on port 80 to your application domain URL will be routed to
>   this port.

Comment: ye saw that, my https endpoint port is ${https.port} where ${https.port} = 8081 inside the properties file

Comment: this is my endpoint:<https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="${https.port}" path="customerquote" mimeType="application/json"  keep-alive="true" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="httpsConnector"/>

Comment: this is the https connector:
 <https:connector name="httpsConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true">
         <https:tls-key-store path="netsuitekeystore.jks" keyPassword="nuixtest" storePassword="nuixtest"/>
    </https:connector>

Answer (score 1):

An HTTPS listener requires a TLS configuration.

Please refer this link
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Building+an+HTTPS+Service